# How to set the out-length with the Web Crypto API SubtleCrypto.deriveKey() for PBKDF2

Tags: javascript, pbkdf2, webcrypto-api

According to the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/deriveKey) a simple example to derive a password with PBKDF2 is

```
  return window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    'raw', 
    encoder.encode(password), 
    {name: 'PBKDF2'}, 
    false, 
    ['deriveBits', 'deriveKey']
  ).then(function(key) {
    return window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
      { "name": 'PBKDF2',
        "salt": encoder.encode(salt),
        "iterations": iterations,
        "hash": 'SHA-256'
      },
      key,
      { "name": 'AES-CTR', "length": 128 }, //api requires this to be set
      true, //extractable
      [ "encrypt", "decrypt" ] //allowed functions
    )
  }).then(function (webKey) {
    return crypto.subtle.exportKey("raw", webKey);
  })
```

As one can see the API lets you choose:

- key derivation function (and it's underlying hash)
- salt
- iterations
- raw key material (ie. password)

However as far as I can see there is no options for choosing the out-length. It *seems* that the cipher suite parameter `{ "name": 'AES-CTR', "length": 128 }` influences the out length, but you can only choose 16 and 32 byte.

For example with 10,000 rounds, salt: 'salt', password: 'key material' with 128 it will result in the following 16 bytes:

```
26629f0e2b7b14ed4b84daa8071c648c
```

whereas with `{ "name": 'AES-CTR', "length": 256 }` you will get

```
26629f0e2b7b14ed4b84daa8071c648c648d2cce067f93e2c5bde0c620030521
```

How do I set the out length apart from 16 or 32 byte? Do I have to truncate it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*deriveKey* function with AES algorithm option returns you **AES** key. Possible AES key length parameters are following (in **bits**):

- 128
- 192
- 256

So, you are able to choose only from them when using AES cipher. In my opinion, it's a **bad** idea to modify a key generated from *deriveKey* function. First of all, you will break an algorithm standard, and also in future you will have a problem with using truncated keys.

But if you want just to use PBKDF2 and derive **bits** from a password, you can use *deriveBits* function. Here is an example:

```
window.crypto.subtle.deriveBits(
        {
            name: "PBKDF2",
            salt: window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16)),
            iterations: 50000,
            hash: {name: "SHA-256"}, // can be "SHA-1", "SHA-256", "SHA-384", or "SHA-512"
        },
        key, //your key from generateKey or importKey
        512 //the number of bits you want to derive, values: 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 512, 1024, 2048
    )
    .then(function(bits){
        //returns the derived bits as an ArrayBuffer
        console.log(new Uint8Array(bits));
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.error(err);
    });
```

More examples  here - https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#pbkdf2---derivekey .

Also, I have tested possible values for derive bits, and they are powers of 2 (from 8 to 2048).

I hope it will help you. Remember, if you want just use AES cipher better use default values and *deriveKey* function.

Comment: Ah, I see. It was just an API missunderstanding. Unfortunatly it seems there is no doc für https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/deriveBits so that sucks. Im used to the deriveBits style (Im expecting only bytes).

Comment: Yes, you are right, no docs for *deriveBits*. Maybe, they decided to simplify API and add *deriveKey* instead *deriveBits*.